# Numbers between powers of consecutive primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

So if we try to categorize numbers based on the number of their prime factors we would have something as following where $L_n$ is the list of numbers with $n$ prime factors.
$$
L_1 : 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ...
$$
$$
L_2 :2^2, 2 \times 3, 3^2, 2\times5, ... 
$$

$$
...
$$

$$
L_n : 2^n, ...,3^n, ..., 5^n, ...p^n
$$

Here on $L_n$ the dots show the products of primes where the sum of their powers is $n$. For example between $2^3$ and $3^3$ there is $2 \times\ 2 \times 3$ ,  $2 \times\ 3 \times 3$ , etc..

My question now is whether there is a formula that can give the amount of members of $L_n$ between $p_i^n$ and $p_{i+1}^n,$ in terms of $i$ and $n$? Or since it's obvious that there must at least be $n-1$ numbers between them, what's the upper bound?

Comment: There is also $2\times2\times5$ in $L_3$

Comment: @Empy2 yeah, I just wanted to mention some examples

Comment: Bertrands postulate says that there is always a prime between $n$ and $2n$, so an easy upper bound for $p^n_{i+1}-p^n_i$ is $(2^{n}-1)p^n_i$. Other results imply that we can replace $2$ by any real number $>1$ if we restrict to $i$ sufficiently large. But I agree with @AdamRubinson. It is not clear at all what you mean, try to be more precise please.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Yes that's right that's what I mean, also the uppercase P was a typo, fixed that.

Comment: Bertrands postulate will not help a lot. It says there is at least one prime number between $n$ and $2n$, and there is generally more than $n/ln(n)$ prime numbers in this interval. So much higher than the limit given by Bertrands.  Probably we can estimate density of numbers with k factors. We already know density of numbers with  only 1 factor.

Answer (score 0):

In any interval, we can correctly estimate how many prime-numbers in this interval, and alse how many integers with $k$ factors.

I don't know any theory on this, so I did some tests.

Between $500 000 000$ and $510 000 000$ :

Numbers with 1 factor are 4.74% ; 2 factors : 15.9% 3:22.88% 4:21.3% 5:15.2%  6:9.25% 7:5.14% 8:2.68% 9:1.37% 10:0.66% 11:0.33% 12:0.16%

And divide by 2 for any following value.

Between $730 000 000$ and $740 000 000$

Numbers with 1 factor are 4.66% ; 2 factors : 15.69% 3:22.78% 4:21.3% 5:15.34%  6:9.34%  7:5.21% 8:2.73% 9:1.39%
And divide by 2 for any following value.

Proportion of numbers with 5 factors or more increase very slowly.

So, when you know the length of the interval between $p_i^n$ and $p_{i+1}^n$, you can estimate how many integers with $k$ factors in this interval. It doesn't work if $p_i$ is very small (2, 3, 5 ... 53 ...)

Comment: Thanks. I already saw some questions on which they've discussed the frequency of numbers based on the number of their factors which shows that numbers with 3 factor are up to very large numbers the most frequent but not consistent all the way which is in some way understandable.

Comment: As the OP's examples show, the pertinent stat for a number $N$ being $n$ means not that $N$ has $n$ prime factors, but that $N$ is the product of $n$ primes. That is $n=\Omega(N)$. But your percentages work only for the ranges you tested. Your results do not scale to values of $N$ of other magnitudes. The distribution of $\Omega$ over a range of values of $N$ depends on the size of these values. Broadly speaking, the mean of $\Omega$ goes up as $\ln\ln N$ goes up.